# Gallery stripped from excerpt of post

Tags: filters, gallery

I'm having trouble with galleries being stripped/filtered out of the content of the post excerpts before the "read more" click (the galleries load just fine when you click and read the post all by itself on a full page).

Something in the template is stripping that out (there are lots of filters in the theme options, none of which have worked turning them off).

Does anyone know what code to look for that might be stripping something like the standard wordpress galleries?  I'm somewhat new to Wordpress and not great at php, so wondering if anyone knew what I should look for.

Side notes:  Other templates display it correctly, other gallery plugins do the same thing, there is an extra file content_gallery.php, I don't see any "filters" besides using functions to strip.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that WordPress strips out all formatting and shortcodes (including the `[gallery]` shortcode) from `the_excerpt()` function. Using `the_content()` instead will fix this problem.

Comment: @bungeshea, nope, using twentytwelve / eleven / ten / etc. all of them show the gallery in the post before clicking read more. :/

Comment: Twenty Twelve and Twenty Eleven uses `the_content()` everywhere except on searches where `the_excerpt()` is used. Twenty Ten always uses `the_content()`

Comment: omg bungeshea you are an absolute LIFESAVER!  I knew it was something incredibly simple like that!!!!  Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :) I've posted the solution as an answer so you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme most likely uses [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt) function. This function takes the post content and removes all formatting and shortcodes (including the `[gallery]` shortcode), and truncates it to a certain amount of characters.

What you could try is removing this function, and replacing it with [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content), which still respects the `<!-- more -->` tag in posts, but correctly displays shortcodes and HTML formatting.

Comment: works perfectly!  For my template, it was in the content.php file for anyone searching for what to replace, and the original template designer used theme_get_content() and theme_get_excerpt() instead of what's above.  

I hope those aren't old depreciated wordpress functions and just custom functions by the designer (I think they're custom because I think I recall the_content() in other places somewhere.